# Gradle CLI: How to see documentation for specific option

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

How do I get the particular information of an option from gradle?

> It says -?, -h, --help Shows this help message.

So, I can type `gradle -h` for the general page, but how would I know what `gradle tasks --all` does? Typing `gradle tasks -h` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like from the documentation  [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html#sec:listing_task_options), you can list the command line options for a specific task by running:

`gradle -q help —task ${taskName}`